# why laravel 5.4 don't have see() method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.4

has laravel 5.4 removed the see() method? It was  used in phpunit test for views. 
It was available for use before in laravel 5.2 but now command prompt says.

> call to undefined method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 uses [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk) to perform browser testing.
 
The new method you are looking for is [`assertSee()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#available-assertions).

Comment: but they should provide backword compatability, some or the other way. Correct me if I am wrong.